# How do I make a image overlay a image when a checkbox is checked Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, checkbox

Hello I am trying to setup a web page where, if my customers select certain options a image appears in the Right hand corner, when you select options it overlays other images on that image to show you the final product. I have this code I have played with a little bit from an example and modified to make it work however I am stuck on makeing it show the image and overlays when checkboxes are checked and hide them when unchecked.

**CSS :**

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
#map {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 350px;
    height: 200px;
}
#station_A { 
    top: 5px; left: 85px; 
}
.hover { 
    color: green 
}
```

**HTML :**

```
<div id="map">
    <span id="station_A" class="overlay"><img src="/tn_bandannatop.png>"</span>
    <span id="station_B" class="overlay">Highlight image here.</span>
</div>

<p>
    <span class="hover station_A">Station Alpha</span> is one example.

</p>
```

**JS :**

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.overlay').each(function(i, el) {
        jQuery('.' + el.id)
            .mouseenter(function() { jQuery(el).css('display', 'inline') })
            .mouseleave(function() { jQuery(el).css('display', 'none') });
    });
});
```

UPDATE: [Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/dynfvzsw/1/) 
This is setup for mouse over, however I want to change it to actions of on checkbox checked and unchecked.

UPDATE: Added Checkboxes to the  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dynfvzsw/4/) here. Left mouse over code in for now to show what I want it to do when checkbox is checked.

Comment: If you create fiddle for this, you might get a better number of people responding...

Comment: you probably need to use something like `if ($(yourElement).is(':checked')) { do something }`

Comment: Might be a good idea to start by adding the check boxes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something working on a JSFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dynfvzsw/7/

The Jquery is actually really simple, all you have to do is:

```
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(function() {
    var state = $(this).val();
    //
    $("#"+state).toggleClass("overlay");
});
```

Then all you have to do is add the values to your check boxes in your HTML like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="image" value="station_A">Station Alfa<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="image" value="station_B">Station Beta
```

Comment: Thank you Eric, This is exactly what I wanted! Your a big help Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some tweaks to your fiddle that shows/hides two elements based on their corresponding checkbox being checked/unchecked:

> https://jsfiddle.net/dynfvzsw/1/

Here is the basic javascript that makes it run:

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery('.overlay').each(function(i, el) {
        jQuery('.' + el.id).click( function() {
            $('#' + $(this).attr('class')).toggleClass('overlay', !$(this).is(":checked"));
        });
    });
});
```

Basically it adds/removes the class `overlay` with `toggleClass`, which sets the `display` to `none`:

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
}
```

Here is the basic html:

```
<span id="station_A" class="overlay"><img src="http://preview.jesybyqcev4e7b9xn83mzparyiafw29nwvpl11qsrsmunmi.box.codeanywhere.com/tn_bandannatop.png"></span>
<span id="station_B" class="overlay">Highlight image here.</span>
<input class='station_A' type='checkbox'/>
<input class='station_B' type='checkbox'/>
```